# What is wrong with my python gas pump code?

Tags: python

So I'm working on this assignment and wrote this basic code but something is wrong and I can't figure out what exactly.

The purpose is just to capture the steps used during the gas pumping.  For example: making payment, selecting gas, etc.

```
#Fuel pump
def main():
    #pin value
    PIN=1234;pin=0;fuelgrade=0;rate=0;success=False

    pin=getinput(pin)
    pin,PIN,fuelgrade,rate,success=processing(pin,PIN,fuelgrade,rate,success)
    display(success)

#Input functions
def getInput(pin):
    pin=int(input("Please enter your PIN:"))
    return pin

#Processingfunctions
def processing(pin, PIN, fuelgrade, rate, success):
    if pin==PIN:
        success=True
        gas=int(input("How much gas do you need?:"))
        fuelgrade=(int(input("Which fuel grade do you want:"))
        rate = fuelgrade*gas        
        return (pin, PIN, fuelgrade, rate, success)
    else:
        success=False
        return pin, PIN, fuelgrade, rate, success

#Output Function
    def display(success):
        if success:
            print("Total is: $", format(rate,'7.2f'), sep='')
        else:
            print("Invalid Pin")

main()
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Where do you get results that are not correct?

Comment: it's on line 21, it says syntax error, I can't figure out what exactly

Comment: nevermind I figured it out

Comment: What’s up with this formatting? Semicolons?! Where is the whitespace?! Not even a space after prompting for input! Why aren’t your names in the `lower_case_with_underscores` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are just a few syntax errors in your code. I fixed them for you below:

```
#Fuel pump
def main():
    #pin value
    PIN=1234;pin=0;fuelgrade=0;rate=0;success=False

    pin=getInput(pin)
    pin,PIN,fuelgrade,rate,success=processing(pin,PIN,fuelgrade,rate,success)
    display(success, rate)

#Input functions
def getInput(pin):
    pin=int(input("Please enter your PIN:"))
    return pin

#Processingfunctions
def processing(pin, PIN, fuelgrade, rate, success):
    if pin==PIN:
        success=True
        gas=int(input("How much gas do you need?:"))
        fuelgrade=int(input("Which fuel grade do you want:"))
        rate = fuelgrade * gas
        return (pin, PIN, fuelgrade, rate, success)
    else:
        success=False
        return pin, PIN, fuelgrade, rate, success

#Output Function
def display(success, rate):
    if success:
        print("Total is: $", format(rate,'7.2f'), sep='')
    else:
        print("Invalid Pin")

main()
```

You forgot to capitalize the `i` in `getInput(pin)`.
You also needed to pass in the `rate` parameter into `display(success, rate)`.
There was also a problem with indentation for the `display` function. It should be at the top level.

Comment: I did the changes you suggested, thank you, but it still gives error at line 21 rate=fuelgrade*gas. It says syntax error.

Comment: Copy paste error? The code in the answer works for me